# How to insert multiple RadioButtonFor value into database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonlist, radio-group, radiobuttonfor

I want to insert 3 value of radio button into Database using MVC.
User need to select one material for each categories(Walls,Roof,Floor)

[image]

Currently the user can only select one value (may need to do grouping).But when I do grouping only the structInfo value is inserted into database. I need all the 3 value inserted into database.

This is how the database design look like
[image]

the struct inf(walls,roof,floor) the materialinfo is (bricks.concrete,woods, etc)

So can I make all the 3 value choosed by user save into database?

This is my view

```
 @foreach (var structIN in Model.structInfo)
                {
                    if (structIN.structId.Equals(1))
                    {
                        @Html.Label(structIN.structNm) @:&nbsp; &nbsp;

                        foreach (var material in Model.materialInfo)
                        {
                            if (material.materialId.Equals(1) || material.materialId.Equals(2) || material.materialId.Equals(3))
                            {
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.buildInfo.materialId, material.materialId)@Html.Label(material.materialNm)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.buildInfo.structId, new { Value = structIN.structId })

                            }

                        }
                    }

                    else if(structIN.structId.Equals(2))
                    {
                        <br />
                        @Html.Label(structIN.structNm) @:&nbsp; &nbsp;

                        foreach (var material2 in Model.materialInfo)
                        {
                            if (material2.materialId.Equals(2) || material2.materialId.Equals(4) || material2.materialId.Equals(5))
                            {
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model2 => model2.buildInfo.materialId, material2.materialId)@Html.Label(material2.materialNm)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model2 => model2.buildInfo.structId, new { Value = structIN.structId })

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else if (structIN.structId.Equals(3))
                    {
                        <br />
                        @Html.Label(structIN.structNm) @:&nbsp; &nbsp;

                        foreach (var material3 in Model.materialInfo)
                        {
                            if (material3.materialId.Equals(6) || material3.materialId.Equals(3))
                            {
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model3 => model3.buildInfo.materialId, material3.materialId)  @Html.Label(material3.materialNm)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model3 => model3.buildInfo.structId, new { Value = structIN.structId })

                             }
                        }
                }
                }
```

Comment: You cant, at least not without redesigning your database. You either need 2 fields in your `BuildingInfo` table, `Walls`, `Roof` and `Floor` that contain a reference to `MaterialInfo`, or you need a 4th table for the relationships (containing columns for `BuildingInfoId`, `StructInfoId` and `MaterialInfoId`)

Comment: Your `MaterialInfo` model also does not seem correct. It should contain a property for a relationship to the `StructInfo` table

Comment: Oo, Thank you so much Stephen, can I  create the relationship in my viewModel? do you have any reference to that?

Comment: Yes, but you need to redesign your database. I assume you would want the option of adding other `StructInfo` objects, for example `Ceiling` that might have a choice of say 'Plasterboard', 'Acoustic Tile' etc. in which case you need a 4th database table for the relationships

Comment: Ok, so from what I understand is, I need to have 4th table, in that table, I need to have columns for BuildingInfoId, StructInfoId and MaterialInfoId? and after that i need to have specific model class for relationship? or I just need to redesign the database only?

Comment: You will need an extra model relating to the 4th table (say `StructuralMaterial`), and then your `BuildingInfo` model will also contain `public virtual ICollection<StructuralMaterial> StructuralMaterials { get; set; }` which will hold the data from that table

Comment: I see, thank you for your guidance Stephen, I am going to do it and will let you know :)

Comment: I am not allowed to add table so I have decided to make a class.  I dont know how to show it to you .I will put in in asnwer bt I still need your help in saving the data into database.

Answer (score 1):

**my GET method**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RegisterForm()
    {
        PopulateStructMaterialData();
        using (var dataBase = new TMXEntities())
        {
            var model = new RegisterInfoPA()
            {
                //OTHER CODES
            };

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

**Populating Data**

```
        private void PopulateStructMaterialData()
    {
        var list = new List<strucMaterial>
        {
            new strucMaterial{ifOthers = "", materialId = 1, materialNm = "Bricks", structId = 1, structNm = "Walls", insuranceReqId = 0, isSelected = false},
            new strucMaterial{ifOthers = "", materialId = 2, materialNm = "Concrete", structId = 1, structNm = "Walls", insuranceReqId = 0, isSelected = false},
            new strucMaterial{ifOthers = "", materialId = 3, materialNm = "Woods", structId = 1, structNm = "Walls", insuranceReqId = 0, isSelected = false},

            new strucMaterial{ifOthers = "", materialId = 2, materialNm = "Concrete", structId = 2, structNm = "Roof", insuranceReqId = 0, isSelected = false},
            new strucMaterial{ifOthers = "", materialId = 4, materialNm = "Tiles", structId = 2, structNm = "Roof", insuranceReqId = 0, isSelected = false},
            new strucMaterial{ifOthers = "", materialId = 5, materialNm = "Zinc", structId = 2, structNm = "Roof", insuranceReqId = 0, isSelected = false},

            new strucMaterial{ifOthers = "", materialId = 3, materialNm = "Woods", structId = 3, structNm = "Floor", insuranceReqId = 0, isSelected = false},
            new strucMaterial{ifOthers = "", materialId = 6, materialNm = "Reinforced Concrete", structId = 3, structNm = "Floor", insuranceReqId = 0, isSelected = false},

        };
       ViewBag.populatebuilding = list;
    }
```

**In View**

```
  List<Insurance.ViewModels.strucMaterial> viewModelSM = ViewBag.populatebuilding;
  for(int i=0; i<viewModelSM.Count; i++)
  {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => viewModelSM[i].structNm)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => viewModelSM[i].structId)

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => viewModelSM[i].isSelected)

                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => viewModelSM[i].materialId)
                    @Html.Label(viewModelSM[i].materialNm)
  }
```

**My POST method**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterForm(RegisterInfoPA viewmodel, List<strucMaterial> list)
    {
        using (var dataBase = new TMXEntities())
        {
            var model = new RegisterInfoPA()
            {
              //OTHER CODES
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //OTHER CODES
                var register = viewmodel.reg;
                var personalinfo = viewmodel.pinfo;

                //Save Register
                db.registers.Add(register);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //Retriving required Id's
                var getid = register.registrationId;
                var getRegTypeID = register.regisTypeId;

                //SAVE PERSONAL INFO
                personalinfo.registrationId = getid;
                db.personalInfoes.Add(personalinfo);
                db.SaveChanges();

              //---HOW SHOULD I SAVE THE CHECKBOX HERE?-----------                                  
              **> tHIS IS MY CODE, BUT IT IS NOT WORKING**
                foreach(var item in list) (<< error starts here)
                {
                    buildingInfo.materialId = item.materialId;
                    buildingInfo.structId = item.structId;
                    buildingInfo.insuranceReqId = item.insuranceReqId;
                    db.buildingInfoes.Add(buildingInfo);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
       }
    }
```

I am always getting this error

*System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

How the proper code should look like? Thank you.